# How to extract a Chart.js chart with reactive attributes as a separate component in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, svelte, svelte-component

I have created a *Skeleton Project* using the `npm create svelte@latest myapp` command. Next, I installed the Chart.js with `npm install svelte-chartjs chart.js` and created a simple bar chart:

```
<script>
  import { Bar } from 'svelte-chartjs';
  import { Chart, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js';

  Chart.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale);

  let numbers = [10, 20, 30];
  let dates = ['1/1/2024', '1/2/2024', '1/3/2024'];

  $: data = {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Random Number',
        data: numbers,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239,0.4)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  };

  let options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };

  async function generate() {
    const response = await fetch('/generate');
    let fetchedData = await response.json();

    dates = fetchedData.dates;
    numbers = fetchedData.numbers;
  }
</script>

<h1>Fetch Data from API endpoint</h1>

<button on:click={generate}>Request</button>

<div>
  <Bar {data} {options} />
</div>
```

It fetches the data from the `/generate` API endpoint which generates from 1 to 10 random numbers with values ranging from 10 to 30. Additionally, the dates are produced according to the length of the random numbers. If the <kbd>Request</kbd> button is pressed, the bar chart will update its labels and data values. The output looks like this:

[image]

The content of the `routes/generate/+server.js` file (simulating the API endpoint) that updates the `numbers` and `dates` array is the following:

```
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';

function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function generateDates(numDates) {
  var today = new Date();
  var dates = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < numDates; i++) {
    let dateString = today.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
    dates.push(dateString);
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
  }

  return dates;
}

export function GET() {
  let length = getRandomNumber(1, 10);
  let numberData = Array.from({ length: length }, () => getRandomNumber(10, 30));
  let dateData = generateDates(length);
  
  return json({dates: dateData, numbers: numberData});
}
```

The length of the data from the endpoint is randomly selected between 1 and 10 and the starting date begins with the current date. An example output of the API endpoint:

> {"dates":["2/8/2024","2/9/2024","2/10/2024"],"numbers":[14,23,23]}

I would like to extract the `Bar` chart-specific code into a separate component for more readability and reusability. However, the `labels` and the `datasets[0].data` attributes reactively change when fetching (generating) new data.

How to extract a Chart.js chart with reactive attributes as a separate component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a component (e.g. `BarChart.svelte`) and extract the chart-specific code:

```
<script>
  import { Bar } from 'svelte-chartjs';
  import { Chart, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js';

  Chart.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale);

  export let dates = [];
  export let numbers = [];

  $: data = {
    labels: dates,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Random Number',
        data: numbers,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239,0.4)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(98,  182, 239, 1)',
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    ]
  };

  let options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  };
</script>

<Bar {data} {options} />
```

You need to export the `dates` and `numbers` variables so they can be updated from another component. Import the new component into the original component and assign the fetched values using the bar chart's attributes:

```
<script>
  import BarChart from './BarChart.svelte';

  let numbers = [10, 20, 30];
  let dates = ['1/1/2024', '1/2/2024', '1/3/2024'];

  async function generate() {
    const response = await fetch('/generate');
    let data = await response.json();

    dates = data.dates;
    numbers = data.numbers;
  }
</script>

<h1>Fetch Data from API endpoint</h1>

<button on:click={generate}>Request</button>

<div>
  <BarChart {dates} {numbers} />
</div>
```

> Note: The `BarChart.svelte` component is created next to the fetching component. In the future, it is advisable to create a `components` folder if there are multiple components.